# Getting data from multidimensional arrays (render array) in twig

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, drupal-7, twig

I have a render array for a form in my D7 module that looks like this:

```
'form' => 
  array
    '#id' => string 'demo-form' (length=9)
    '#action' => string '/sprint07/' (length=10)
    'name' => 
      array
        '#title' => string 'Username' (length=8)
        '#maxlength' => int 13
        '#size' => int 15
        '#type' => string 'textfield' (length=9)
        '#required' => boolean true
        '#input' => boolean true
        '#autocomplete_path' => boolean false
   ... snip ...
```

I'm using `twig-for-drupal` to create a theme, but I can't seem to get the values back, I've tried `{{ form['name']['#type'] }}`, `{{ form.name.#type }}`, `{{ form.name['#type'] }}` and so on, but they all come back blank.

Other fields such as `form['#action']` works fine, so how should I access the information more than one array in? I can't change the module too much as the php template in its native state uses `render(form);`

-- Update --

Added some more debugging to this, and seems that I can use `{{ form|dump('v') }}` to show me the whole array as above, but when I do `{{ form.name|dump('v') }}` I just get a string, which I assume means that twig is automatically detecting its a render array, and "helpfully" converting it for me.. So I guess that makes my question: how do I turn off the auto-rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it isn't currently possible to do this on a case-by-case basis, TFD is currently set up to auto-render anything it thinks is a render array, and to turn this off you need to set autorender to FALSE in `twig_get_instance()`. I've tried this myself however and it still seems to be turning the array into a string, so this could be a bug within TFD, or I just don't understand the usage, which is equally, if not more, likely.

From [ReneB's sandbox](http://drupal.org/sandbox/ReneB/1075966):

> Autorender
>
> This version of the TWIG engine uses auto render to prevent themers get RSI from typing {{node.field_somefield|render}} for every single field they want to render from the render array (of doom) so the can safely type {{node.field_something}}
>
> On rendering of the compiled template TFD check if the called variable is a string, callable or array. If it's a string it simple does echo $string, if it's a callable it return a proper method() for it. And if it's an array, it assumes it's a renderable array and maps it to the render($string); method of drupal.
>
> This way the objects hidden with hide() are respected.
>
> To turn this is for now, you have to set autorender to FALSE in the twig_get_instance() method of twig.engine.
>
> I'am working on a {% noautorender %} {% end noautorender %} block structure.

Answer (score 1):

"name" sub array don't contain the "#id" key.

try if work

```
{{ form.name.#title }}
```

Comment: id was a bad example, I have the same problem for the keys that do exist as well.